# AngularJS version 1 - Application Insights integration

Tags: angularjs, azure-application-insights

I am currently supporting an application that is built using AngluarJS Version 1. I am quite new to this.

I have a task to integrate the Azure Application Insights into this application. The below reference link gives info about the integration using npm
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript

I am not sure how to write the below code in AngularJS, this gives the error.
import { ApplicationInsights } from '@microsoft/applicationinsights-web'

Please help or if there are any references please share.

Comment: You probably need the this version: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/javascript#snippet-based-setup

Comment: Thanks @JacobStamm for your input. Is it possible to use npm instead of "Snippet based setup". I need to push additional data to azure

Answer (score 0):

Either we can use **[NPM Setup](https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-js#npm-setup-ignore-if-using-snippet-setup)** and **[Snippet Setup](https://github.com/microsoft/applicationinsights-js#snippet-setup-ignore-if-using-npm-setup)**.

#### For NPM

```js
npm i --save @microsoft/applicationinsights-web
```

#### Configure Angular APP and Include Dependencies

You can use the **environment.ts** file to store the ***Instrumentation Key***

```js
export const environment =  
{  
    .  .  . 
    appInsights:  { instrumentationKey:  '<Your Instrumentation Key>'  
    }  
};
```

Add **Dependency** to ***package.json*** Restore it using **npm install**

```js
"dependencies":  {  "@microsoft/applicationinsights-web":  "~2.4.4",
...
}
```

Refer [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/angular-how-to-add-application-insights-to-an-angular-spa/#step-3-consume-the-application-insights-sdk-in-typescript) for further steps